# Make sure that the first element after the shuffle in JavaScript is not the same as the last element in the previous shuffle

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, random, shuffle

This fiddle demonstrates my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/petebere/fhg84je2/

I would like to make sure that every time a user clicks a button a random element from the array will be displayed. The problem is that sometimes when the new shuffle is carried out, the first element in the newly shuffled array is the same as the last element in the previously shuffled array. On these occasions when the user clicks the button the same element is displayed. The user has to then click the button again (or more times) to display a different element. I would like to avoid this.

I've tried introducing the if statement to shuffle again if the first element is equal to the last element but this does not seem to work.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

The HTML code:

```
    <div id="container">
        <button id="clickHere">Click here to pick a random element from the array</button>
        <div id="resultDiv"></div>
    </div><!-- container -->
```

The JavaScript code:

```
/* define the array with a list of elements */
var arrayList = [
"1st element in array</br>",
"2nd element in array</br>",
"3rd element in array</br>",
];

/* define the function to shuffle the array */
function shuffleArray() {
for (var i = arrayList.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = arrayList[i];
    arrayList[i] = arrayList[j];
    arrayList[j] = temp;
}
}

/* execute the shuffleArray function */
shuffleArray();

/* button event initiating the randomiser function */
document.getElementById('clickHere').onclick = function () {
    randomiser ();
}

/* populate the resultDiv for the first time */
document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = arrayList[0];

/* define the array index value for the first click */
var arrayIndex = 1;

/* define the main function */
function randomiser () {
    document.getElementById('resultDiv').innerHTML = arrayList[arrayIndex];
    arrayIndex = (arrayIndex+1);
    if (arrayIndex>arrayList.length-1) {
        arrayIndex = 0;
        var lastArrayElement = arrayList[arrayList.length-1]
        shuffleArray();
        var firstArrayElement = arrayList[0];
        if (firstArrayElement == lastArrayElement) {
            shuffleArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

The two different solutions suggested by 1) SpiderPig and 2) Jonas-Äppelgran have solved my problem.

This is an updated fiddle with the first solution which uses a combination of `push` and `shift` methods: https://jsfiddle.net/petebere/axatv0wg/

This is an updated fiddle with the second solution which uses a `while` loop instead of an `if` statement: https://jsfiddle.net/fhg84je2/2/

Both solutions work perfectly, however my preferred solution is the second one as I find it easier to understand.

Comment: Not sure I followed, but wouldn´t removing the element you show from the array prevent it from re-appearing in your other shuffles?

Comment: If you find the first element of the shuffled array is the same as the last element of the previous array, why don't you just swap the first and last elements of the shuffled array?  Your method of calling `shuffleArray()` again does not guarantee that the newly shuffled array won't have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a `while` instead of the `if` check when looking if the randomly generated string will be the same as last time.

Psuedocode: `while (old == new) { randomize(); }` This won't stop looping/randomizing until old is not new.

See updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhg84je2/2/)

Comment: Your suggestion has solved my problem and it is very easy to understand for me. I have accepted it as an answer. I would vote your answer up, however I don't have sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do a small change to your code.

Instead of

```
if (firstArrayElement == lastArrayElement) {
  shuffleArray();
}
```

try this

```
if (firstArrayElement == lastArrayElement) {
  arrayList.push(arrayList.shift());
}
```

Comment: your suggestion has solved my problem. However I find it slightly harder to understand than the solution suggested by jonas-Äppelgran. I would vote your answer up, however I don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: My code just removes the first element from the list and adds it at the end. Seems more efficient than shuffling over and over until you get an acceptable result.

Comment: I may in the end go with your solution as you are right - it seems more efficient. I just wasn't aware of the push and shift methods.